# Why is my javascript function being called on all rows after single checkbox check?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

In my MVC 3 Applcation, I want to call my upload function (createUploader()) every time a checkbox is checked for a row that has a specific empty column cell.
However the createUploader() gets applied to each row where this cell is empty.

Html in my view checkbox code:

```
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectecals" value="@Model.ElementAt(index).Id"/></td>
```

The cell in each table row that is either has a value (CertName) or is empty and is assigned a class used to identify in javascript.

```
  @if (Model.ElementAt(index).CertName != null)
             {
                 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ElementAt(index).CertName)</td>
             }
             else
             {                    
                <td class="file-uploader-attachment-Class"></td>
             }
```

My javascript so far:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    function handleCheckbox() {

            if ($(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                createUploader();
                $(this).find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').removeClass("upload-placeholder-unchecked");
            }
            else {
                $(this).find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').addClass("upload-placeholder-unchecked");
                $(this).find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').html($('#myHTML2').html());
            }
    }

    $('tr').each(handleCheckbox);
    $('tr').on('click', handleCheckbox);

    function createUploader() {

        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('file-uploader-attachment-Class');

        Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function (element) {

            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                element: element,
                sizeLimit: 2147483647, // max size
                action: '/CalibrationViewer/AttachmentUpload',
                allowedExtensions: ['xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'csv', 'txt', 'rtf', 'zip', 'zipx', '7z'],
                params: {
                    customer: CUST_NAME,
                    calibrationId: CAL_ID
                },
                multiple: false,
                debug: false,

                onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJson) {
                    var resultMessage = document.getElementById('resultMessage');
                    alert(responseJson.msg);
                }

            });

        });
    }
});
```

So far when the page is loaded, if there is no value for the Cert cell "No file" is displayed.
If a user checks the checkbox of this row every with "No File" uses the createUploader() function .

Ideally I want this function being called (displaying the upload btn) when the checkbox for that specific row is checked, make sense ?

[image: before check]
[image: After check]

Comment: if you want the behavior bound to checkbox, why are you applying click handler to row instead of to the checkboxes?

Comment: To give an honest answer, because I am useless with javascript. Could you give me an example of the right way to handle the checkbox check.

Comment: use a change handler on the checkboxes instead and add logic based on checked property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify where to apply your function createUploader()

```
function handleCheckbox() {

            if ($(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                createUploader($(this));
                $(this).find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').removeClass("upload-placeholder-unchecked");
            }
            else {
                $(this).find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').addClass("upload-placeholder-unchecked");
                $(this).find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class').html($('#myHTML2').html());
            }
    }

 function createUploader(container) {

    var elements = container.find('.file-uploader-attachment-Class');

    Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function (element) {

        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: element,
            sizeLimit: 2147483647, // max size
            action: '/CalibrationViewer/AttachmentUpload',
            allowedExtensions: ['xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'csv', 'txt', 'rtf', 'zip', 'zipx', '7z'],
            params: {
                customer: CUST_NAME,
                calibrationId: CAL_ID
            },
            multiple: false,
            debug: false,

            onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJson) {
                var resultMessage = document.getElementById('resultMessage');
                alert(responseJson.msg);
            }

        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Just to expand on this question a little the action CalibrationViewer/AttachmentUpload expects a ID, however regardless of the checkbox selected, the last row ID is returned each time ? ...any ideas?

Comment: You need to specify the corresponding ID in the FileUploader call 
with container.find(':checkbox').val()
Maybe you can add a param with it

Comment: not sure I follow each checkbox contains value="@Model.ElementAt(index).Id" so in the createUploader function could add something like var id = container.find(':checkbox').val() ??

Comment: Yes, in your function createUploader, you will create an uploader specificly for the row you pass in parameter. In this function you access the ID of the checkbox of the row with container.find(':checkbox').val() You just have to gave it to your function FileUploader and use it on the server side

Comment: Got it correct ID is now passing to action CalibrationViewer/AttachmentUpload , my next task will be to refresh that cell with the file name of the newly uploaded file , thanks for the help.